# "ndd" equivalent of "ethtool" on Solaris

Tags: command-line, rsync, solaris, network-interface

I've to restore a large file from a NAS backup on Solaris 10 ZFS. I'm using this following command:

```
 rsync -av user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:from/NAS/files/system to/solaris/files/system
```

And I've got this error:

```
 Disconnecting: Corrupted MAC on input.
 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (3778664937 bytes received so far) [receiver]
 rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)
 rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [receiver=3.1.0]
 rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(837) [generator=3.1.0
 rsync Disconnecting: Corrupted MAC on input.
```

After a little research the solution should be:

```
 ethtool -K eth0 tx off rx off
```

As the ethtool command doesn't exist on Solaris, I should use the ndd utility in interactive mode. I didn't find any good explanation and the man page is poor, for getting the equivalent of the command line above. I'm missing something maybe.

Comment: *After a little research the solution should be: `ethtool -K eth0 tx off rx off`*  If that's the solution, something is wrong because that's a solution for a *Linux* bug in handling network connections.  Is this a gigabit or faster network?  Has someone wrongly disabled autonegotiation?  Per the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation#Overview):  *The standards for 1000BASE-T, 1000BASE-TX and 10GBASE-T require autonegotiation to be always present and enabled.*

Comment: looks like an XY-problem, why is MAC corrupted ? commands of use can be `dladm`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of rsync are you using, and have you tried using a different version or different method to move the data?

The error message you're seeing is hinting of packet corruption occurring somewhere on the line.  Ref:  [SSH error messages](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/ssh_messages_code_bad_packet) for a good explanation of the message you're getting.